# How can I set an the image of an imageview for a specific file in Android?

Tags: android, uri, mime-types

I am working on an android app and I was wondering if it was possible to load image files directly in the image view? For example if you have a list of photos, the image view should show the image of each item. Also, how would you do it for apk files. For example, when you look at apk files using a file manager, they usally have the app icon to the right of each apk file.

Here is my code:
item is equal to a File from the sdCard directory.

```
(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fileimage).setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(item));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
File img = new  File(“PATH/image.jpg”);
if(img.exists()){

    Bitmap myBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img.getAbsolutePath());
    ImageView fileimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fileimage);
    fileimage.setImageBitmap(myBmpp);

}
```

Comment: Nice! it works!! But I get an error saying it is out of memory when I try to load the pictures folder.

Comment: Paste the LogCat, then write here the memory of the device and the image size you're using, because setting the imagebitmap loads it into the memory.

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5457): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: I have a picture folder with about 40+ images and when I clicked it to open it, it crashed and I got that error.

Comment: Are you receiving this in the Emulator, I mean do you test this on a real device or on a phone or tablet?

Comment: If Emulator - then increase the AVM. If not - then `    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.fileimage));
    System.gc();
    }

    private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
        if (view.getBackground() != null) {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
    }`

Comment: I think the error has something to do with an image being too big.